# javascript regular expression to remove trailing numbers in parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace/append `something (22)` string to `something`, using some kind of expression matching something is not a constant its always different but the part (integer) is always the same. cheers

**EDIT**

I see that this something is a bit confusing(for me as well). Here is what I mean. I have a string - a word . Which contains alpha expression(a word, any word) one single space opening and closing paranthesis and inside of the an intiger. Now I'd like to replace blank space, paranthesis and integer inside to replace with nothing and leave just the alpha part of the string.

Ex:

```
Java (77)
Javascript (22)
Car (11)
Carpet (15)
```

After regex it should look like this :

```
Java
Javascript
Car
Carpet
```

Note, the regex is performed on each word seperatly, I just wrote couple of examples to make things more clear to read and understand. Thank you

Comment: You should better explain the expected format of `something`.
For example "`something` is single alphanumeric word", or "`something` is a one or at most two words starting with a digit".

Comment: The way your question is phrased: `s = "something"; s = s + "something (22)"`

Comment: What Andrea said. Now an answer like: "by performing `some` regex or other string manipulation" would be as good as an answer as the question is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
var text = "Java (77) Javascript (22) Car (11) Carpet (15)";
text.replace(/(\w+) \(\d+\)/g,"$1");   // returns "Java Javascript Car Carpet"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `something` as `\w -> A-Za-z0-9_`, this will convert `something (22)` to `something`

```
yourstring=yourstring.replace(/(\w+)\s*\(\d+\)/g,"$1")
```

or just remove numbers in brackets

```
yourstring=yourstring.replace(/\s*\(\d+\)/g, "")
```

Comment: ummm as I can read .. you assume that my string starts with s, I've edited the question to make my question more undrestandable(I hope).tnx

Comment: no, its not only for string starts with s, \s is whitespace which include space not the char "s"