# PHP Remove Value of String with Variable Numbers

Tags: php, string

Basically from a database I am getting data that is formatted like this nameofproject101 Now this could continue to increase so eventually it could be nameofproject1001 my question is how can I trim off the number and just get the name of the project. I thought about using `substr` but since I dont know the length always I cant really do that. Since the numbers differ I dont think I can use `str_replace` is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use regular expression to strip out trailing numbers.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123334/javascript-regular-expression-to-remove-trailing-numbers-in-parenthesis

Comment: Will the name of the project itself contain numbers?

Comment: @erisco From the database yes it is stored like 'nameofproject101' I need it to be 'nameofproject', but what I need to do with the data, I dont need the numbers so I need them stripped off.

Comment: @atrljoe I believe erisco was asking whether the name (without the trailing numbers) could contain numbers. E.g. _r2d2translator1001_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like something is way off about your database scheme. You should probably try to do refactor/normalize your scheme.

But in the meantime, you can use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim) to trim all numbers off of the right side.

```
$val = rtrim($val, '0123456789');
```

**Examples**

```
Input               Output
nameofproject1001   nameofproject
nameofproject       nameofproject
n4me0fproj3ct1001   n4me0fproj3ct
```

Answer (score 1):

for string like, `project12V123`, It is better to do this

```
$text = `project12V123`;
$text = preg_replace('/([\w]+)([^0-9])([0-9])+$/', '$1$2', $text);
```

Will return:

```
Project12V
```

or use `rtrim`:

```
$text = rtrim($text,'0123456789');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use regular expressions:

```
$fullname = "nameofproject101";
preg_match("/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/i", $fullname, $matches);
$name   = $matches[1];
$number = $matches[2];
echo "'$fullname' is '$name' followed by '$number'";
```

Comment: This will turn `version2project101` into `version`. OP probably wants `version2project`.

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $string);
```

Comment: @Kristian That's what I was hinting at. ;)

Comment: The above will turn `r2d2translator1001` into `rdtranslator`. Probably not what OP wants.